# regex pattern to find this particular string in file_get_contents in PHP

Tags: php, regex, string, curl, file-get-contents

I'm looking to get this value 'B00DS4KJR4' enclosed in  tags from a url by using file_get_contents() function in PHP. However, I'm failing to write the correct regex to find the value from this html source code the page:

```
<span class="a-text-bold">ASIN:
                    </span>
                    <span>B00DS4KJR4</span>
```

Can you help me to write the correct regex to find that particular value on the page ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123131/determine-if-10-digit-string-is-valid-amazon-asin  See the regex in the second answer.  Should give you a pretty good starting point.

Comment: You should *never* parse HTML with regex. Use [a PHP DOM parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regular expression like the following also presented on [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/lZ9tP3/2). This looks for a `<span>` with any attributes, containing the string `ASIN:` in the innerHTML followed by another `<span>` and captures the contents of the second `<span>`.

```
$html ='<span class="a-text-bold">ASIN:
                </span>
                <span>B00DS4KJR4</span>';

if (preg_match('/<span\s[^><]*>\s*ASIN:\s*<\/span>\s*<span>\s*([^><]*)\s*<\/span>/i', $html, $m)) {
    $asin = $m[1];
    print $asin;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match_all('/<span>(.*)<\/span>/',$the_html,$the_result_array);
```

The first `span` doesn't match with the regex because it has class in it, the other ones which are written like `<span>anything</span>` will be found.

Comment: yeah, i know that but thing is that there could be many strings enclosed in the span tags. But i wanted to find only right after the ASIN:  text. So, I would do that ?